# Get string from filename to output file plus string inside same file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, output, cut

I have some directory with multiple files with the extention .failed
This number of files can change every day.
This files have the following format:

**file1_string2_1.failed:**

```
FHEAD|string2|20170109000000|20170125024831
THEAD|150001021|20170109121206||
TDETL|4000785067||1|EA|||RETURN|||N
TTAIL|1
THEAD|150001022|20170109012801||
TDETL|4000804525||1|EA|||RETURN|||N
TTAIL|1
FTAIL|6
```

I need to extract the next 2 strings after THEAD| to a output file separated by comma. I also need the filename and the string2 extracted to this output file. 
Note that string2 can be used from the filename or from the FHEAD tag.

**expected output:**

```
file1_string2_1.failed,string2,150001021,20170109121206
file1_string2_1.failed,string2,150001022,20170109012801
file2_string2_1.failed,string2,150001023,20170109100904
file2_string2_2.failed,string2,150001024,20170109031206
file2_string2_3.failed,string2,150001025,20170109081207
file3_string2_1.failed,string2,150001026,20170109141203
file3_string2_2.failed,string2,150001027,20170109121208
file4_string2_1.failed,string2,150001028,20170109171206
```

For now i have the following command:

```
awk -F'|' '$1 == "THEAD" {print FILENAME, $2}' OFS=, *.failed > failed_transactions.out
```

The output that im getting is:

```
file1_string2_1.failed,150001021
file1_string2_1.failed,150001022
file2_string2_1.failed,150001023
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split `FILENAME` into underscore-separated fields and place the result in an array

```
split(FILENAME,a,"_")
```

After that, it's just a matter of adding the required elements to the `print` statement

```
print FILENAME, a[2], $2, $3
```

So

```
awk -F'|' '$1 == "THEAD" {split(FILENAME,a,"_"); print FILENAME, a[2], $2, $3}' OFS=, *.failed > failed_transactions.out
```